# Merging MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge three queries and I want to get an aggregate result for these three queries, how can i achieve this in MySQL?

My queries

```
SELECT 
  order_table_no,
  count(bill_no),
  sum(finaldiscount) 
from order_master     
where `ORDER_TABLE_NO` like 'HOME%' 
  and order_time >= '2015-01-01' 
  and order_time <= '2015-01-20'

SELECT 
  distinct(ORDER_TABLE_NO),
  sum(order_quantity*order_item_price) AS order_master_FINALDISCOUNT, 
  count(bill_no) 
FROM `order_master` order_master 
WHERE date(order_master.`ORDER_TIME`) >= '2015-01-01' 
  AND date(order_master.`ORDER_TIME`) <= '2015-01-20' 
  and order_table_no not like 'HOME%' 
  and order_table_no not like 'TAKE%' 
GROUP BY ORDER_TABLE_NO

SELECT 
  order_table_no,
  count(bill_no),
  sum(finaldiscount) 
from order_master 
where `ORDER_TABLE_NO` like 'TAKE%' 
  and order_time >= '2015-01-01' 
  and order_time <= '2015-01-20'
```

Comment: Firstly format your code properly so people can read it easily. You need to learn about JOINS to achieve your goal http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: What should be the result of the "merge"?

Comment: You say you want to merge, but how? Will UNION ALL do? BTW, DISTINCT is not a function, it works on whole rows, not on single columns - and makes no sense when combined with GROUP BY as in this code.

Comment: i have to get three columns order_table_no,count(bill_no),sum(finaldiscount)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit weird that your first and last query don't have any group by clauses. This doesn't require any joins - just use the MySQL IF Control Flow Function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
select
  order_table_no,
  count(bill_no),
  IF(order_table_no like 'TAKE%' or order_table_no like 'HOME%', sum(finaldiscount), sum(order_quantity * order_item_price)) finaldiscount
from
  order_master
where
  order_time >= '2015-01-01' and
  order_time <= '2015-01-20' 
group by
  order_table_no
```